# How to build debian package with CPack to execute setup.py?

Tags: python, cmake, package, deb, cpack

Until now, my project had only **.cpp**  files that were compiled into different binaries and I managed to configure **CPack** to build a proper **debian package** without any problems.

Recently I wrote a couple of python applications and added them to the project, as well as some custom modules that I would also like to incorporate to the package.

After writing a `setup.py` script, I'm wondering how to add these files to the **CPack** configuration in a way that `setup.py` get's executed automatically when the user installs the package on the system with `dpkg -i package.deb`.

I'm struggling to find relevant information on how to configure CPack to install custom python applications/modules. Has anyone tried this?

Comment: Actually, the package should contain the *result* of setup.py in form of files.

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298504/using-cmake-with-setup-py ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it but it's not very simple. I'll do my best to explain the procedure so please be patient.

### The idea of this approach is to use *postinst* and *prerm* to install and remove the python application from the system.

In the **CMakeLists.txt** that defines the project, you need to state that **CPACK** is going to be used to generate a **.deb package**. There's some variables that need to be filled with info related to the package itself, but one named `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA` is very important because it's used to specify the location of **postinst** and **prerm**, which are standard scripts of the *debian packaging system* that are automatically executed by **dpkg** when the package is installed/removed.

At some point of your **main** `CMakeLists.txt` you should have something like this:

```
add_subdirectory(name_of_python_app)

set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL_IN_ONE_PACKAGE 1)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "fake-package")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "ACME")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "fake-package - brought to you by ACME")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0.2")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "1")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "2")
SET(CPACK_SYSTEM_NAME "i386")

set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER "ACME Technology")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "libc6 (>= 2.3.1-6), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.4.2-12), python2.6, libboost-program-options1.40.0 (>= 1.40.0)")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/name_of_python_app/postinst;${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/name_of_python_app/prerm;")
set(CPACK_SET_DESTDIR "ON")

include(CPack)
```

Some of these variables are **optional**, but I'm filling them with info for educational purposes.

Now, let's take a look at the scripts:

**postinst**:

```
#!/bin/sh
# postinst script for fake_python_app

set -e

cd /usr/share/pyshared/fake_package
sudo python setup.py install
```

**prerm**:

```
#!/bin/sh
# prerm script
#
# Removes all files installed by: ./setup.py install
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/pyshared/fake_package
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/fake_python_app
```

If you noticed, script **postinst** enters at `/usr/share/pyshared/fake_package` and executes the **setup.py** that is laying there to install the app on the system. Where does this file come from and how it ends up there? This file is created by you and will be copied to that location when your package is installed on the system. This action is configured in `name_of_python_app/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
install(FILES setup.py
        DESTINATION "/usr/share/pyshared/fake_package"
)

install(FILES __init__.py
        DESTINATION "/usr/share/pyshared/fake_package/fake_package"
)

install(FILES fake_python_app
        DESTINATION "/usr/share/pyshared/fake_package/fake_package"
)

install(FILES fake_module_1.py
        DESTINATION "/usr/share/pyshared/fake_package/fake_package"
)

install(FILES fake_module_2.py
        DESTINATION "/usr/share/pyshared/fake_package/fake_package"
)
```

As you can probably tell, besides the python application I want to install there's also 2 custom python modules that I wrote that also need to be installed. Below I describe the contents of the most important files:

**setup.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='fake_package',
      version='1.0.5',
      description='Python modules used by fake-package',
      py_modules=['fake_package.fake_module_1', 'fake_package.fake_module_2'],
      scripts=['fake_package/fake_python_app']
     )
```

**_*init*_.py**: is an empty file.

**fake_python_app** : your python application that will be installed in /usr/local/bin

And that's pretty much it!

Comment: Could you use install(DIRECTORY fake_package DESTINATION /usr/share/pyshared/ USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS) ?

Comment: I don't know, I guess you are going to have to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

A `setup.py` file is the equivalent of the `configure && make && make install` dance for a standard unix source distribution and as such is inappropriate to run as a part of a distributions package install process.  See [this discussion](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Python) of the different ways to include Python modules in a `.deb` package.

Comment: Thank you, I've read that before but I can't use those tools and I must do it with CMake/CPack.

Comment: Then you may have to manually implement the [Debian Python Policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/) yourself, but I'm pretty sure you're making your life hard by not using existing tools for building debs.

Comment: I find CPack very straight forward and easy to use. But the thing I need it to do is a little complicated. I'll post my approach here so you guys can judge it :)

Comment: I guess the link of discussion is broken.