# Distribute Python library created with SWIG/CMake

Tags: python, windows, installation, cmake, swig

We have a C++/Fortran software project with a Python front-end generated with SWIG. We build the project on various platforms (Linux, Windows, OS X) using CMake, which works fine for the most part. The compiler we use depends on the platform (gcc or clang on Linux, XCode+gfortran on Mac, MinGW on Windows).

Now, installing a C++ compiler, CMake, SWIG, etc. and compiling is a bit too much for most users so we would like to be able to distribute the code with a simple binary installer (.exe file in Windows, deb-package in Ubuntu etc.).

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using CMake already, I'd recommend [CPack](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake%3aPackaging_With_CPack).

Here are the [docs for v2.8.8](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cpack.html), or you can run `cpack --help` for more info.

Comment: Right. Can I expect CPack to work also for the installation of Python packages?

Comment: Can you give some insight into how CPack integrates with Python? How do you find the right place to install modules to on Windows? Without that this answer isn't particularly helpful. (Linux has been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7918913/168175))