# Is there a general strategy for converting linux builds into mac builds?

Tags: macos, opencv, build, cmake, distribution

I am trying to build a software library cvBlobs which is designed to help people track blobs using python opencv.  In principle it should be possible to build and install the linux distribution, however, in practice I don't know how to do this.  Using CMake does not work.

Generally, to make this happen, what approach would one take?  What are the steps?  Many people would like to use this library in the Mac OSX environment however they are not able to get past installation.

A good answer could be general, or specific to my problem.

http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) is a great cross-platform build system. I always write my cross-platform applications using this platform so I can build the software on Mac/Windows/Linux without pain.

One time I even configured [CMake to build a Debian package to install a python application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7249440/176769) I was working on.