# Build a python package with setup.py in CMake

Tags: python, build, cmake, package, setup.py

EDIT: The question is a bit too long. Here is my real question: How can I build and install a python package with setuptools (setup.py) inside CMake? The detail of my code is shown below (but with an out-of-source build method, the method with the source is working).

---

I have a project where I need to distribute my own python package. I made a setup.py script but I would like to build & install it with CMake.

I followed [Using CMake with setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298504/using-cmake-with-setup-py) but it only works with one `CMakeLists.txt` alongside the `setup.py` and the python folder and without executing cmake from a build directory.

With this layout :

```
Project/
--build/
--lib/
----python/
------folder1/
------folder2/
------data/
------...
------__init__.py
----setup.py
----CMakeLists.txt
--CMakeLists.txt
```

and with `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8 FATAL_ERROR)
add_subdirectory(lib)
(..)
```

and with `lib/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_program(PYTHON "python")

if (PYTHON)
    set(SETUP_PY_IN "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/setup.py")
    set(SETUP_PY    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/setup.py")
    set(DEPS        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/python/__init__.py")
    set(OUTPUT      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/build")

    configure_file(${SETUP_PY_IN} ${SETUP_PY})

    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${OUTPUT}
                       COMMAND ${PYTHON}
                       ARGS setup.py build
                       DEPENDS ${DEPS})

    add_custom_target(target ALL DEPENDS ${OUTPUT})

    install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ${PYTHON} ${SETUP_PY} install)")
endif()
```

and with `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name="python",
    version="xx",
    author="xx",
    packages = find_packages(),
    package_data = {'': ['*.txt']},
    description="Python lib for xx")
```

When I run `CMake` from build directory and then `make`, the target is built but with nothing. It is as if no packages were found. The installation installs the python package without `.py` files.

Comment: Have you tried setting the WORKING_DIRECTORY in add_custom_command?

Comment: You should use all the paths relative to the current source directory. Put a line such as `DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` and then make all packages relative to that dir so it builds out of source.

Answer (score 1):

setuptools doesn't know about the out of source build and therefore doesn't find any python source files (because you do not copy them to the binary dir, only the `setup.py` file seems to exist there). In order to fix this, you would have to copy the python source tree into the `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`.

Answer (score 1):

https://bloerg.net/2012/11/10/cmake-and-distutils.html suggests setting `package_dir` to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` in `setup.py`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out previously you can copy your python files to the build folder, e.g. something like this

```
set(TARGET_NAME YourLib)
file(GLOB_RECURSE pyfiles python/*.py)
foreach (filename ${pyfiles})
    get_filename_component(target "${filename}" NAME)
    message(STATUS "Copying ${filename} to ${TARGET_NAME}/${target}")
    configure_file("${filename}" 
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/${target}" COPYONLY)
endforeach (filename)
```

and then have a build target like this

```
add_custom_target(PyPackageBuild
        COMMAND "${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}" -m pip wheel .
        WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        COMMENT "Building python wheel package"
        )
add_dependencies(PyPackageBuild ${TARGET_NAME})
```

In case you do not want to use pip you have to adjust the PyPackageBuld target.

If you want to include some shared library, e.g. written in C++, which is build by other parts of your cmake project you have to copy the shared object file as well to the binary folder

```
set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES
        PREFIX "${PYTHON_MODULE_PREFIX}"
        SUFFIX "${PYTHON_MODULE_EXTENSION}"
        BUILD_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}/libs"
        BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
set(TARGET_PYMODULE_NAME "${PYTHON_MODULE_PREFIX}${TARGET_NAME}${PYTHON_MODULE_EXTENSION}")
```

and add it to the `package_data` in `setup.py`

```
....
package_data={
        '': ['libs/YourLib.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so']
    }
```

You can find a working example using `pybind11` for `C++´ bindings at https://github.com/maximiliank/cmake_python_r_example

Comment: The cython version, archticture args in the shared library name in the `setup.py` can be obtained via `import sysconfig` and `f'libs/YourLib{sysconfig.get_config_var("EXT_SUFFIX")}'`.