# Creating a python package (deb/rpm) from cmake

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake, setuptools

I am trying to create a python package (deb & rpm) from `cmake`, ideally using `cpack`. I did read

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/rpm.html and,
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/deb.html

The installation works just fine (using component install) for my shared library. However I cannot make sense of the documentation to install the python binding (glue) code. Using the standard cmake install mechanism, I tried:

```cmake
install(
  FILES __init__.py library.py
  DESTINATION ${ACME_PYTHON_PACKAGE_DIR}/project_name
  COMPONENT python)
```

And then using brute-force approach ended-up with:

```
# debian based package (relative path)
set(ACME_PYTHON_PACKAGE_DIR lib/python3/dist-packages)
```

and

```
# rpm based package (full path required)
set(ACME_PYTHON_PACKAGE_DIR /var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages)
```

The above is derived from:

```
debian % python -c 'import site; print(site.getsitepackages())'
['/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.9/dist-packages']
```

while:

```
rpm % python -c 'import site; print(site.getsitepackages())'
['/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

It is pretty clear that the brute-force approach will not be portable, and is doomed to fail on the next release of python. The only possible solution that I can think of is generating a temporary `setup.py` python script (using `setuptools`), that will do the install. Typically `cmake` would call the [following process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70017390/136285):

```
% python setup.py install --root ${ACME_PYTHON_INSTALL_ROOT}
```

My questions are:

- Did I understand the cmake/cpack documentation correctly for python package ? If so this means I need to generate an intermediate `setup.py` script.
- I have been searching through the cmake/cpack codebase (`git grep setuptools`) but did not find helper functions to handle generation of `setup.py` and passing the result files back to `cpack`. Is there an existing `cmake` module which I could re-use ?

---

I did read, some alternative solution, such as:

- [How to build debian package with CPack to execute setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249440/how-to-build-debian-package-with-cpack-to-execute-setup-py)

Which seems overly complex, and geared toward Debian-only based system. I need to handle RPM in my case.

Comment: why not creating a wheel package instead ?

Comment: @Mizux any documentation on cpack+wheel out there, thanks ?

Comment: Just thinking of directly creating a whl package like this https://github.com/Mizux/python-native/ that you can uploat to pypi.org etc no rpm involved.
otherwise you may be interested in https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/cmake/python-install.cmake.in

Comment: @Mizux For your suggestion #1, I cannot upload company code to pypi.org. As for suggestion #2, this closely resemble my own answer. However it does not deal with the complexity associated with absolute path cmake `install()` commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in [my other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70031306/136285), the ugly part is dealing with absolute path in cmake `install()` commands. I was able to refactor the code to avoid usage of absolute path in `install()`. I simply changed the installation into:

```
install(
  # trailing slash is important:
  DIRECTORY ${SETUP_OUTPUT}/
  # "." syntax is a reliable mechanism, see:
  # https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22616
  DESTINATION "."
  COMPONENT python)
```

And then one simply needs to:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/")
set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX "/")
include(CPack)
```

At this point all install path now need to include explicitely `/usr` since we've cleared the value for `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`.

The above has been tested for deb and rpm packages. `CPACK_BINARY_TGZ` does properly run with the above solution:

- https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22925

Answer (score 0):

I am going to post the temporary solution I am using at the moment, until someone provide something more robust.

So I eventually manage to stumble upon:

- https://alioth-lists.debian.net/pipermail/libkdtree-devel/2012-October/000366.html and,
- [Using CMake with setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298504/using-cmake-with-setup-py)

Re-using the above to do an `install` step instead of a `build` step can be done as follow:

```
find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter)

set(SETUP_PY_IN "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/setup.py.in")
set(SETUP_PY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/setup.py")
set(SETUP_DEPS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/project_name/__init__.py")
set(SETUP_OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/build-python")

configure_file(${SETUP_PY_IN} ${SETUP_PY})

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/setup_timestamp
  COMMAND ${Python_EXECUTABLE} ARGS ${SETUP_PY} install --root ${SETUP_OUTPUT}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/setup_timestamp
  DEPENDS ${SETUP_DEPS})

add_custom_target(target ALL DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/setup_timestamp)
```

And then the ugly part is:

```
install(
  # trailing slash is important:
  DIRECTORY ${SETUP_OUTPUT}/
  DESTINATION "/" # FIXME may cause issues with other cpack generators
  COMPONENT python)
```

Turns out that the documentation for `install()` is pretty clear about [absolute paths](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22925):

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#introduction

> ```
> DESTINATION
> [...]
> As absolute paths are not supported by cpack installer generators,
> it is preferable to use relative paths throughout.
> ```

For reference, here is my `setup.py.in`:

```py
from setuptools import setup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(name='project_name_python',
          version='${PROJECT_VERSION}',
          package_dir={'': '${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}'},
          packages=['project_name'])
```

---

You can be fancy and remove the `__pycache__` folder using the `-B` flag:

```
COMMAND ${Python_EXECUTABLE} ARGS -B ${SETUP_PY} install --root ${SETUP_OUTPUT}
```

---

You can be extra fancy and add debian option such as:

```
if(CPACK_BINARY_DEB)
  set(EXTRA_ARG "--install-layout" "deb")
endif()
```

use as:

```
COMMAND ${Python_EXECUTABLE} ARGS -B ${SETUP_PY} install --root ${SETUP_OUTPUT} ${EXTRA_ARG}
```